# Improve query to be less repetitive

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to improve this query? I see two problems here -

1. Repetitive code
2. Hard coded strings

The first CTE calculates count based on 18 months. The second CTE calculates count based on 12 months.

```
    with month_18 as (
        select proc_cd, count(*) as month_18 from 
        (
            select distinct patient, proc_cd from 
            service 
            where proc_cd = '35'
            and month_id >= (select month_id from annual)
            and month_id <= '202009' --This month should be 18 months from the month above
            and length(patient) > 1
        ) a 
        group by proc_cd
    ),
    month_12 as 
    (
        select proc_cd, count(*) as month_12 from 
        (
            select distinct patient_id, proc_cd from 
            service 
            where proc_cd = '35'
            and month_id >= '201910'
            and month_id <= '202009' --This month should be 12 months from the month above
            and length(patient) > 1
        ) a 
        group by proc_cd
    )
    select a.*, b.month_12 from 
    month_18 a 
    join month_12 b 
    on a.proc_cd = b.proc_cd
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select proc_cd,
       count(distinct patient) filter (where month_id >= (select month_id from annual) and month_id <= '202009') as month_18,
       count(distinct patient) filter (where month_id >= '201910' and month_id <= '202009')
from service 
where proc_cd = 35 and
      length(patient) > 1
group by proc_cd;
```

If you have to deal with date arithmetic on the month ids, you can convert to a date, do the arithmetic and convert back to a string:

```
select to_char(to_date(month_id, 'YYYYMM') - interval '12 month', 'YYYYMM')
from (values ('202009')) v(month_id);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How do I convert `202009` to be 12 months from `201910` without hard coding it.

Comment: Why are you using strings rather than dates for this purpose?

Comment: Not my design and I have no control over it.